# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Error with Static Class member

Tags: c++, static, x86-64

I keep getting an error code I've seen on here a lot, yet most answers seem to comment on issues with header files which I do not have (I don't think?). sortKey is a private static member and I get an error in my setters and getters I believe.

```
 bool Student::setSortKey(int userKey) {
   sortKey = SORT_BY_LAST;
   if(!validSortKey(userKey))
      return false;
   sortKey = userKey;
   return false;
}
static int getSortKey() { return sortKey; }
```

And the error...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Student::sortKey", referenced from:
      Student::setSortKey(int) in main.o
      Student::getSortKey() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have thought about this for a while, and I cannot figure out what it is that is wrong. Do I need to be referencing the sortKey within the setter using a Student:: (thats the class name)? All the methods in the class are defined as static as well. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Ask better questions: [MCVE]!

Answer (score 5):

Supposed you have a declaration like

```
class Student {
    // ...
    static int sortKey;
};
```

Provide a definition for `Student::sortKey` in your `.cpp` file:

```
int Student::sortKey = SORT_BY_LAST;
```